# Is it possible to call normal controller Method/ActionResult from Web API Controller's Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, cross-platform

Is it possible to call ActionResult/Method of normal MVC Controller from Web API's method?

```
public class MyAPIController : ApiController
{
    public string CallActionResultOfMVCController()
    {
         //Here I want to call method/ActionResult from MyMVCController something like below.
         //var result = WantToCallMyMVCMethod();
         //return result;
    }
}

public class MyMVCController : Controller
{
    public string WantToCallMyMVCMethod()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you want to do it! I think you have a problem in your scenario. usually , if we'll want to call a MVC controller  , it's maybe call from pages. but you can call a API method from page or another MVC controller and etc... finally , if you want to search on online page you will see about 'how to call api controller method from mvc controller'

Comment: This does seem like an XY problem. There should be no reason to do this. If there’s common code it shouldn’t be in a controller method. Please explain what you’re trying to achieve by this.

Comment: @AminSaadati : Yes I do call API controller methods from normal controller and there is no issue in that.
But there is one situation where I need this reverse scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Although,I told you in above comment (it's maybe you have a problem in your scenario ),anyway you want to do it. you can use to below link for do it .
Be successful.
 [C# how to call MVC Action method from console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643490/c-sharp-how-to-call-mvc-action-method-from-console-application)